# How to approach to HR after rejecting offer

Tags: job-offer

A week ago I was qualified for a software engineer position and HR offered me the position. Because of salary issues during negotiation, I declined the offer. Now after I thought more about it I think that I should join the company. So my questions are:

- Can I approach them again since I declined the offer myself.
- if yes then what would be the right way to approach them.

Comment: It's likely they've moved on to other candidates, but it can't hurt to ask. Say you've reconsidered and would like to accept their offer, if it still stands.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can send them a simple note like so:

> Hi XXX,
>
> After some further thought, I've decided that I would like to come and work for your company at the previously discussed salary (YYY) and benefits package (ZZZ).  Please let me know if the offer still stands.  I look forward to hearing back from you.
>
> Regards,
>   Raj